# How can I store a list of actions and have these set as true of false with a function call?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to have my application hold information about 
network activity. So I created this function:

```
networkStart = (action: string = null) => {
    this.action = action;
    this.net = true;
    this.netd = true;
}

networkStop = (action: string = null) => {
    this.net = false;
    this.netd = false;
}
```

But there's a problem. I want to be able to store details of 
the activity in something like an array or an object that has the action name as the key. So that when some
network activity starts then the information is recorded in 
that array as true for that action and when it stops it is changed to false.

How can I convert this so it uses an array to store the actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `HashMap` that maps an `action` name to its properties:

```
interface ActionDetails{
    net:boolean;
    netd:boolean;
}

class Foo{
    // This thing 
    actions:{[name:string]:ActionDetails} = {};

    networkStart = (action: string = null) => {
        this.actions[action].net = true;
        this.actions[action].netd = true;
    }

    networkStop = (action: string = null) => {
        this.actions[action].net = false;
        this.actions[action].netd = false;
    }
}
```

the `"null"` will be a default action of sorts.